# iphone - forcing button to acknowledge touch programmatically

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

When you touch a UIButton it hides for a fraction of second and then it executes its action. This fast "blink" is the feedback the user needs to know that the button has been clicked.

In the project I am doing, I need to select the button programmatically, as if the user had clicked it. In other words, the same behavior has the button had been clicked by the user... a fast blink and execution of its action.

Is this possible to do?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change in the appearance of the button is effected by setting the button's `highlighted` property.  The property is automatically set to `YES` when the user touches down on the button, and back to `NO` when she releases.

The `highlighted` property is writable, so you can set it `YES` yourself to simulate a touch down.  You'll probably want to use `+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:]` to set it back to `NO` after a short interval.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple, and probably there is a better solution. 
First, use images to your button, and when you have to fire the button, you just change the button's image in the normal state to the pressed image, and after that, replace it back to the original. You can simply do it with a timer.